# Command line FTP client with REST operator support to download a part of file

Tags: command-line, ftp

I am going to write a script that will download tail of file from FTP server, for example, last 10KB of the file. I tried a lot of FTP clients, but none of them is suitable to do this task. Windows built-in FTP command line utility does not support rest command. CoreFTP requires administrative privileges to run, WinSCP supports only resume transfer, FileZilla does not have command line utility at all. I cannot download whole file, because it is too large. FTP protocol definitely supports it, because it has REST command, which resumes transferring a file. Any ideas how to do this task? Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `curl -C offset ftp://blah/foo/bar.xyz`